# pkg/sftp Much Slower than Linux SCP, Why?

Tags: go, scp

With standard `scp` (version: `1:7.6p1-4ubuntu0.3`) on Ubuntu 18.04, transferring a 110GB file to another host takes roughly 6-8 minutes.

When using Go's `pkg/sftp`, it takes double the amount of time:

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/melbahja/goph"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    auth, err := goph.Key("your/key", "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    client, err := goph.NewConn(&goph.Config{
        User:     "someUser",
        Addr:     "someHostname",
        Port:     22,
        Auth:     auth,
        //Timeout:  time.Duration(timeout) * time.Second,
        Callback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    file := "/some/file"
    start := time.Now()

    local, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer local.Close()

    ftp, err := client.NewSftp()
    // VARIATION 1 => ftp, err := client.NewSftp(sftp.MaxPacketUnchecked(1 << 16))
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer ftp.Close()

    remote, err := ftp.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer remote.Close()

    /*
    VARIATION 1 => buffer := make([]byte, 1 << 16)
    VARIATION 1 => _, err = io.CopyBuffer(remote, local, buffer)
     */

    _, err = io.Copy(remote, local)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    duration := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(duration)
}
```

Note: I even attempted to increase the size of the read buffer (and tcp max packet size) with the commented out lines (see `VARIATION 1`), and it made no difference.

Any ideas as to why, and how to speed up the Go equivalent?

Comment: scp and sftp are different protocols, they are not really comparable. How does it compare to openssh/sftp?

Comment: @JimB Good point. I just tried using https://github.com/bramvdbogaerde/go-scp and it's the same problem however, still takes 12 minutes. So it looks like the bottleneck is likely io.Copy...

Comment: I would say the bottleneck is more likely the ssh package, as the protocol implementation is hard to optimize for throughput. You can easily wrap the file in a `bufio.Reader`, but speeding up the pipe is probably what's needed.

Comment: pkg/sftp supports concurrent upload, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that pkg/sftp supports concurrent upload and the concurrent upload  speed is quite similar to linux `sftp` command.

Here the client initialization:

```
sftpConn, err := sftp.NewClient(sshConn,
        sftp.UseConcurrentReads(true),
        sftp.UseConcurrentWrites(true),
        sftp.MaxConcurrentRequestsPerFile(64),
        // Big max packet size can improve throughput.
        sftp.MaxPacketUnchecked(128*agentio.KiB),
        // Beware of customizing max packet size for download! 
        // On download, big max packet size can cause "connection lost" error.
    )
```

Here is how you can use it, pay attention to `ReadFrom`:

```
func sftpUpload(c *sftp.Client, r io.Reader, path string) error {
    fp, err := c.Create(path)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("create destination file: %w", err)
    }
    defer fp.Close()

    _, err = fp.ReadFrom(r)

    return err
}
```

To use concurrent upload the reader's underline struct has to be bytes.Reader, io.LimitedReader or satisfy one of the following interfaces:

- Len() int
- Size() int64
- Stat() (os.FileInfo, error)

It's required to determine amount of bytes to upload.

If `ReadFrom` can't determine reader's size than it will fallback to single thread upload.

Check the `ReadFrom` source code:

```
func (f *File) ReadFrom(r io.Reader) (int64, error) {
    f.mu.Lock()
    defer f.mu.Unlock()

    if f.c.useConcurrentWrites {
        var remain int64
        switch r := r.(type) {
        case interface{ Len() int }:
            remain = int64(r.Len())

        case interface{ Size() int64 }:
            remain = r.Size()

        case *io.LimitedReader:
            remain = r.N

        case interface{ Stat() (os.FileInfo, error) }:
            info, err := r.Stat()
            if err == nil {
                remain = info.Size()
            }
        }
```

Also, if you pass the reader to ReadFrom which producing a lot of small peaces of data than the throughput will be quite low even with concurrency.